# Как разделить пользователей веб приложения

Tags: java

Захотел написать веб приложение для записи рабочих заказов для исполнителей. Нужно сделать так чтобы исполнитель мог авторизоваться и видеть свои заказы. Так же чтобы он мог их добавлять, изменять или удалять. Само приложение написать не проблема. Хотел это реализовать на spring web. Записывать заказы в postgresql. Авторизацию через spring security. И фронт через vaadin. Но встал вопрос как мне разделить пользователей(исполнителей) заказов. Чтобы каждый пользователь видел только свои заказы и с ними работал. Как это можно реализовать? Чтобы одно приложение запущенное на сервере умело разделять пользователей. И давало доступ к из данным.

Comment: просто связывать исполнителей и заказы и показывать исполнителям только заказы, в которых они указаны...в чем проблема?

Comment: Получается создать две таблицы. И при выборке всегда проверять. А как после того как человек авторизоваться  мне тогда именно его заказы выдавать. Это нужно как то сохранить. Что именно он зашёл. Просто не могу понять как реализовать. Куда сохранять хотя бы имя пользователя который зашёл. И когда он регистрируется добавить его в таблицу пользователей

Comment: Вам предстоит еще долгий путь... Если у вас столько подобных вопросов, то нужно сначала разобраться с ними и потом уже браться за такую задачу. Все их точно не получится осветить в рамках одного вопроса. Но по каждому из остальных достаточно материалов для обучения. Если там будут возникать проблемы с какими то конкретными вопросами и не будет получаться написать что-то конкретное - задавайте тут.

Comment: Зачем разводить демагогия если помочь человеку не хочешь? Я знаю как сделать все кроме того что спросил. Знаю как связать две таблицы. Знаю как их создать и как использовать. Только как из формы авторизации перетащить пользователя не знаю. Мне ещё много чего учить это точно. Но ответить то можно на конкретный вопрос

Comment: Я не развожу демагогию. Вы пришли не в пункт помощи нуждающимся. Это база знаний в которой есть свои правила. Прочитайте справку прежде чем задавать вопрос: [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). В текущем виде вопрос закроется голосованием в очереди проверок т.к. он не соответствует правилам сообщества.

Comment: Я не развожу демагогию, а пытаюсь вас поставить на путь решения вашей проблемы. Я помог сотням людей на данном сайте. Речь не о моем желании, а о том, что вы сами не понимаете что просите и как достичь результатов. Вы помимо вопроса, который обозначен в заголовке мне еще горсть вопросов в комментариях насыпали. `Я знаю как сделать все кроме того что спросил` - если бы вы все знали вы бы не задавали таких пространных вопросов.

Comment: Ну закроется так закроется. Что поделать. Но просто не понимаю вашу мотивация. Вместо того чтобы помочь  вы тратите время чтобы унизить новичка. Который может и задал вопрос неправильно. Но попросил помощи.

Comment: в каком месте я вас унижаю?.. я констатирую факты и объясняю вам как работает сервис.

Comment: Думаю если вы не хотите помогать лучше нам с вами обсуждение не разводить. Думаю кто нибудь другой поможет. А если нет то буду искать другие средства решения.

Comment: Если Вы не измените свое поведение и не будете соблюдать правила, то вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит начать отсюда:

1. [getRemoteUser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser())
2. [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal())
3. [User roles](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String))

Пользователям нужно раздать роли и в соотвествии с ними дать разрешение на выполнение сервисов и рендеринга менюшек.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать